# Show and hide Pane with CSS Transitions using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In my ASP.NET project, I wanted to add a form that when the button clicks, shows the form with the transition.

I found a way of doing that in this location [Project](https://codepen.io/jasesmith/pen/raqBpm)

According to the sample, it has a check box, and when the check box is clicked the form will show from the side view, and again clicked it hides.

But for my project, I have created 2 buttons and I want to show the same with the button click.

```
<button class="btn-primary floating-btn1" id="clickerBranch" onclick="branchOnClick();">Branches</button>
<button class="btn-primary floating-btn" id="clickerService" onclick="serviceOnClick();">Service Prices</button>
```

this is the CSS style I included from the sample project

```
.floating-btn {
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        background: #267410;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        text-decoration: auto;
        color: aliceblue;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-style: oblique;
        position: fixed;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
        right: 20px;
        bottom: 50px;
        border-radius: 50%
    }
.panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        background: #333;
        color: #000000;
        overflow: auto;
        padding: 1em;
    }
 .ServicePanel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        background: aliceblue;
        color: #000000;
        overflow: auto;
        padding: 1em;
    }

    [type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .panel-wrap {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }

    *, *:before, *:after {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    [type="checkbox"] {
        font-size: 1em;
    }
```

These is the separate panels I want to show when each buttons clicked

```
<div class="panel-wrap">
  <div class="panel"> Sample </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-wrap">
  <div class="panel2"> Sample </div>
</div>
```

So I tried to do the same according to the sample, but I couldn't find a way of doing it. Can you help me to solve this? The final output I planned is, that when each button clicks panel and panel2 I want to show and hide with the transition.

This is what I have tried to test.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function branchOnClick() {
        alert("H");
        $("ServicePanel").show();
    }

</script>
```

Comment: You are missing either a `#` or `.` in `$("ServicePanel")`

Comment: Also i cant see any element with id or class ServicePanel

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Sorry, I have updated the question, I tried ``#`` and ``.`` but it not showing. Please check my sample I got from the ``codepen``  ``https://codepen.io/jasesmith/pen/raqBpm`` when the check box clicked it, with the fading effect it show and out. I want to do the same for the button click.

Comment: Your codepen does not use *any* [tag:javascript].   It's a css effect that is applied to `[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .panel-wrap` - ie the css applies when the checkbox is ticked.   You have two options:  1) style your checkbox to look like a button (which is relatively easy and plenty of SO solutions)  2) use javascript instead of css, eg `$("#ServicePanel").addClass("slideout")` where slideout is a css class that does the same as the :checked style above.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I have updated again the question with ``floatingbutton`` style. In my project I have this button roundshape right end . So can I create the same as button style for the checkbox? I have never done this before.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Thanks, I have changed it to look like a button. But the only thing is now when it clicked, panel won't show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
 body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .click_me {
        display: block;
        width: 200px;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    .sidebar{
        width: 320px;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: black;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 99;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: .3s ease-out;
    }

    .showSideBar{
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
```

```html
    <div style="width:100%; height:100vh; background-color:#ccc;">
        <button class="click_me" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div id="myDIV" class="sidebar"></div>
```

```
 function myFunction() {
           var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
           element.classList.toggle("showSideBar");
        }
```